# typescript compiler (tsc) throws error, but only when used in yarn script, otherwise works fine

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, tsc

If I execute:

```
tsc
```

Everything compiles, no issues. Picks up patterns in tsconfig.json

```
# inside package.json
scripts: { 
  "build" : "tsc" 
}

$ yarn build
```

Throws error.

```
error TS6307: File '***' is not in project file list. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

The files are in the pattern, as running `tsc` without yarn yeilds desired effect.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Could you provide project structure and tsconfig.json?